# Java Code in Azure cloud service

Tags: java, azure

I have java code (that generates jasper reports) and I couldn't convert it to .net and I want to run it on a "Cloud Services" how can I run java code into cloud service ? 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you have a look at this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944(VS.103).aspx, you cannot java console programs in azure as it is. You need to have a VM to run it.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy - you can absolutely run Java apps in cloud services (web/worker role instances), and they may be console apps. You just have to supply the jvm and then run it either from a startup script or from your role's `OnStart()`. The Eclipse plugin for Azure (which you referenced in your link) describes exactly how to build a Cloud Service package from Eclipse. Just because the example in that post uses JSP, there's no requirement for that. Of course, you can run in Linux/Windows Server VMs too - all up to you. Run whatever.

Comment: So eclipse pushes jvm along with your code? That's great, thx for the info.

Comment: The Eclipse add-in actually goes one step further: It actually sets things up to grab the JVM (and web server) from blob storage, significantly reducing deployment package size (and allowing for software updates without having to include the JVM with each deployment update.

Answer (score 0):

@Dhana provided a link to a tutorial for pushing a Java app to Azure in Cloud Services (worker role). You could also push to a Web role but it makes less sense since IIS runs in a Web role, and you'll probably want Jetty, Tomcat, or JBoss for your web server.

If you're running a console app, that's fine too - just launch it from a startup script or the `OnStart()` in your `workerrole.cs`.

You'll need to [install the tooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690946.aspx) into Eclipse. At this point, you'll be able to build Azure deployment packages, in a similar way to Visual Studio (The Azure plugin for Eclipse only works on Windows though). Part of the packaging sets up links to the appropriate JVM and web server package, as well as your own jar files.

If, say, you have a console app that listens on a port, you'll just need to make sure you have an input endpoint set up for the port you want to expose.